# Possible Distribution of coins

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

We are given a set of $n$ coins with denominations $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ and a number $x$.

The coins are to be divided between to persons, with the restriction that each person's coins must add up to at least $x$.

For example, if $x=1$, $n=2$, and $v_1=v_2=2$, then there are two possible distributions: one where Person 1 gets coin #1 and Person 2 gets coin #2, and one with the reverse. (These distributions are considered distinct even though both coins have the same denomination.)

I'm interested in counting the possible distributions. I'm pretty sure this can be done in $O(nx)$ time and $O(n+x)$ space using dynamic programming; but I don't see how.

Comment: Are you familiar with the "subset sum" problem?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, I didn't know that problem. I read it briefly on Wikipedia, but don't see the connection with this problem.

Comment: It's *exactly* this problem when $2x = \sum v_i$.

Comment: If you can provide the original url and/or the full text of the problem, you might get much more useful replies.